# Jquery Rails 3... form submits twice... deletes twice... help

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, form-submit

It seems like eveyone has this problem but no one has a laymans terms answer or even a proper solutions.

I have a form that uses ajax to submit the form and automatically adds it to the list below the text field. The form submits twice so i have two identical (apart form the ID) records. Worse still is when you try to delete it wont renew the page because its tried to delete the same record twice.

I hope someone has a great answer out there...
btw im new to rails.
code:

index.html.erb

```
<h1>SSCC</h1>
<div id="orderline_form">
    <%= render 'form' %>
</div>

<ul id="orderlines">
    <%= render :partial => @orderlines.reverse %>
</ul>
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@orderline, :remote => true) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :Order_ID %>
    <%= f.text_field :order_id %><br/>
    <%= f.label :SSCC %>
    <%= f.text_field :sscc %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

_order_line.html.erb

```
<%= content_tag_for(:li, order_line) do %>

<%= order_line.id %> |
<%= order_line.order_id %> |
<%= order_line.sscc %>
(<%= link_to 'Delete', order_line, :confirm => 'Are you sure?',
:method => :delete, :remote => true %>)

<% end %>
```

create.js.erb

```
$('#orderlines').prepend('<%= escape_javascript(render(@orderline))%>');
$('#orderlines > li:first ').effect('highlight', {}, 3000);
$('#orderline_form > form')[0].reset();
```

destroy.js.erb

```
$('#<%= dom_id(@orderline) %>').css('background', 'red');
$('#<%= dom_id(@orderline) %>').hide("fade", {}, 1500);
```

Comment: Can you post the JQuery part (your .js).

Comment: my appliaction .js is :jQuery.ajaxSetup({
 'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")}
})

jQuery.fn.submitWithAjax = function() {
 this.submit(function() {
  $.post(this.action, $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
  return false;
 });
 return this;
};

$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#update_order").submitWithAjax();
})

$("form").submit(function(){
    $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});

Comment: the other files i have our the standard jquery, jquery.min, jquery_ujs,jquery-ui, and rails.js

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It happened to me that "application.js" was stored twice (.../public/assets/application.js and .../app/assets/javascripts/application.js). The Rails 3.2.1 Asset pipeline compiled it and created another one. Check for that and delete the unneeded.

Keep in mind that you might already have other repeated assets, you just started noticing this one because jQuery made it evident.

This link helped me:

http://www.ruby.code-experiments.com/blog/2011/10/another-gotcha-with-the-rails-31-asset-pipeline-or-why-are-my-jquery-ujs-ajax-requests-triggered-twi.html

Comment: Just a heads up, I had this issue and deleting the files did not work, it only worked after I ran `assets:precompile` again and then followed that up with a `assets:clean`. I recommend `assets:clean` over deleting the files manually. +1 for pointing out the root of the problem though.

Comment: I've tried precompiling and cleaning the assets and I've checked if application.js appears twice. It doesn't. Then I restart the server, run the code, and it still submits twice. Why could that be? BTW, it doesn't submit twice on production. Only on development.

Answer (score 1):

On Rails 5, rails-ujs replaces jquery_ujs. Events will trigger twice if both are required

```

// app/assets/javascripts/application.js

//= require jquery_ujs <-- delete this

//= require rails-ujs

```

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have submit buttons disabled after the click on them. it helps to localize the problem.

```
  $("form").submit(function(){
    $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
```

Comment: silly question but where shall i put this code... ive currently got it in my application.js file... and it doesnt work

Comment: put in inside $('document').ready(function(){  ... here ... })

Comment: so the problem into the server side logic. can you copy-past your controller code please?

Comment: {   class OrderLinesController < ApplicationController
  
  def index 
    @orderlines = OrderLine.all
    orderline = OrderLine.new
    
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end}

Comment: def create
    @orderline = OrderLine.create!(params[:order_line])
    
    respond_to do |format|
      if orderline.save
        format.html { redirect_to(orderlines_path,
                    :notice => 'Order Line was Successfully created')}
        format.js
      end
    end
  endef destroy
    orderline = OrderLine.find(params[:id])
    orderline.destroy
    
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to orderlines_path }
      format.js
    end
  end
end
all of the order line have an at-sign btw... just stack overflow wont let me put more than one in the comment box

Comment: **orderline.create** and **orderline.save** is the bug. use **build** in the first case

Comment: **@orderline = OrderLine.build(params[:order_line])** you don't need to fire save 2 times by using **create** and **save** one by one

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Rails 4. I had these settings in my development.rb:

`config.assets.digest = true`
`config.assets.enabled = true`

I deleted these and ran `rake assets:clean`

Now its submits like it should.