# How do I stop a remote form from submitting?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-4, ujs

I have a form that can be used both remotely and normally.

```
= form_for @comment, html: { class: 'comment-form' }, remote: request.xhr? do |f|
  = f.text_area :body
  = f.submit
```

I want the form to submit only if the `body` textarea has content:

```
  $(document).on 'submit', '.comment-form', (e) ->
    text = $(this).find('#comment_body').val()
    false if text.length < 1
```

That code works when the form is not Ajax. But when it's remote, it fails and the form still submits. Why? I also tried:

```
if text.length < 1
  e.preventDefault()
  false
```

I'm using Rails 4 with Turbolinks.

Update: I tried binding the `ajax:beforeSend` event, it still submits:

```
  $(document).on 'page:load', '.comment-form', ->
    $(this).bind 'ajax:beforeSend', ->
      alert "hi"
```

I see no alert...

Answer (score 5):

I'm using `Rails 5.0.0.1` and as described at [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax) documentation in ***Stoppable events*** section you only need to return a `false` value in the `ajax:beforeSend` event to stop the request and prevent the form from being send.

So this works perfectly for me:

```
$(document).on("ajax:beforeSend", "form#messages_form", function (e, data, status, xhr) {
    var len = $.trim($('#message_body').val()).length;

    if (len > 3) {
        console.log("Send form!");
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log("Stopping request...");
        return false;
    }
});
```

I hope it could be useful for somebody else.

Comment: Works. But what is the thing that is causing the form to be submitted twice in the first place?

Comment: I don't know which is your case exactly but in this case the question was how to prevent the form from being sent if something special happens. I had a similar case _the form was being *submitted twice*_ and it was because in a `link_to` I used `remote: true` and at the same time I had and ajax request triggered with one of the `classes` my link was using.

Comment: If the form is already in the DOM upon page load, `$("form#messages_form").on("ajax:beforeSend", function ...)` will suffice.

Answer (score 4):

You could potentially implement a handler for the `ajax:beforeSend` event to prevent your form from being submitted. It looks like the submit stops if your event handler returns `false`.

Wiki: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax

Example implementation: [Stop $.ajax on beforeSend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507079/stop-ajax-on-beforesend)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't get your question, but shouldn't it be enough to add a

```
:required => true
```

to your `text_area` ?

Comment: `required: true` adds an HTML5 attribute that doesn't work on half the browsers. It's not dependable. At least not at this time.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a jquery_ujs issue. Try changing the event to:

```
 $('.comment-form').on 'submit', (e) ->
```

I'm facing the same issue and only this solved the problem.