# Remote Method Understanding?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In rails 3

While using `remote` method form submit, it affects the database twice with the same form values.

controller file:

```
 @user_message = UserMessage.new(params[:user_message])
 if  @user_message.save
   render :update
 else
   render :nothing => true
 end
```

view file:

```
<%= form_tag ('/feedback/user_message'), :method =>'post',  :remote=> true, :id=>'user_message' do%>
      <%= hidden_field_tag 'user_message[user_id]', @user.user_id %>
      <h2><%= @question %></h2>
      <%= text_area_tag 'user_message[msg]',"",  :size=>"40x5" %>
      <%= submit_tag  "Submit"%>
  <% end %>
```

When I hit the submit button it creates two records on the table.
Why?

Comment: Is the form getting posted twice or only one and you just two database entries?

Comment: what does your application.js look like do you have jquery ujs in your assets directory?

Comment: no. `jquery-ujs` is not found in assets directory. and `application.js` is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be couple  of things that might be causing this

may be the ujs file is included twice may may be like

```
//= require jquery_ujs // expected to load from the rails-jquery gem
//= require_tree .     // if any file is present in assets directory hierarchy it will be loaded
```

Or just a bug taking your sleep away

https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/issues/208

check out more solutions

[Jquery Rails 3... form submits twice... deletes twice... help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747236/jquery-rails-3-form-submits-twice-deletes-twice-help)

[Rails 3.1 remote requests submitting twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721502/rails-3-1-remote-requests-submitting-twice)

This may also be related to the understanding of asset pipeline when and how use pecompiled assets.

I always use this config in development mode

`config.server_static_assets = false`

this forces the app to call the assets from app assets

and use precompiled assets from public in production mode

Answer (score 0):

The problem most likely related to asset pipeline

You should precompiled the asset pipeline before.

This will create two copy of rails.js, one in your assets and one in application.js

This is a bug or gotcha in rails 3
See here http://www.ruby.code-experiments.com/blog/2011/10/another-gotcha-with-the-rails-31-asset-pipeline-or-why-are-my-jquery-ujs-ajax-requests-triggered-twi.html

Hope this help

Comment: In my project having only one `application.js` in the directory `app/assets`

Comment: so there is no js in `public/assets` ?