# Rails asset pipeline: JavaScript being executed twice

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, turbolinks

My JavaScript is being executed twice. When I run the Chrome debugger, I noticed that the individual JavaScript file will execute the code the first time, then after that, the `application.js` file will execute the code again.

I believe this is happening because I recently turned precompile off because I was having issues with Heroku. After this I ran `rake assets:precompile`.

Answer (score 11):

**Turbolinks**

You *probably* have an issue with [`Turbolinks`](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) (considering you've included it in your asset pipeline); although this might not be the problem.

Turbolinks is meant to speed up your page load times by loading the `<body>` tag of your new pages with `ajax`, keeping the `<head>` tag intact. This is meant to let your application load just the HTML it needs, but messes up the JS on your page.

If you're having your `JS` fired twice, it *could* be a sign that Turbolinks is interfering with your JS. Because you haven't included any examples from the `logs`, I won't be able to give you any specific information, but you should be able to test this by removing the `turbolinks` include from both your `layout` and your `application` manifest JS file:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => false

#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
//= require turbolinks -> remove this line
```

If you do this, restart your server & reload the page in question. If it still comes back with the erroneous functionality, it means Turbolinks is not the problem (and you should reset all the things you changed)

--

**Events**

The other problem you *might* have is how you're calling / triggering your events. This could be down to a number of reasons, but you should definitely look at how you're calling your JS:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("click", ".element", function(){
    //your stuff here
});
```

We always delegate from the [`document`](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) element of the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) now. Whilst this might cause some resource issues, we've found it makes Rails apps much more robust with the Asset Pipeline, as it allows you to truly identify elements on the page.

If you're trying to trigger an event from a single object on your DOM, you may find that JS will "capture" the event twice (for whatever reason), leading to your issue. Try delegating your events which are being called twice

--

**Functions**

Finally, your `functions` could be the issue.

If you have any [anonymous functions](http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/beware-anonymous-functions/), or functions for specific events, you will need to ensure they are able to be called correct. You should do this by using [page events](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) in JS & [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks#events):

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
var your_function = function() {
    //stuff here
};

$(document).on("page:load ready", your_function);
```

Comment: I am not using turbolinks, unless it is automatically included in rails 3.2.13

Comment: or unless its included in bootstrap 3

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation Richard

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem on a rails 3 app that is not using turbolinks. I was able to fix it by running:

```
rake assets:clean
```

This link helped me:
[Jquery Rails 3... form submits twice... deletes twice... help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747236/jquery-rails-3-form-submits-twice-deletes-twice-help)

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue because of the asset pipeline including both jquery, jquery-ujs, and rails-ujs:

```js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require rails_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Removed rails_ujs and all was fine.